# Magento 1.9.0.1 CE users are unable to login to magento

Tags: magento-1.9, error, paypal

When users try to login to magento or try to use the 'forgot my password' reset link, the following error appears:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'mag1_9.paypalauth_customer' doesn't exist

I tried doing a fresh magento install and do not see this table in the new installations.  I do have paypal payments turned on for the site; but there are no additional payment plugins loaded.

I am able to login to the admin area fine.  Any ideas what the error means?  This is the full page that is displayed:

```
There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mag1_9.paypalauth_customer' doesn't exist

Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `paypala...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `paypala...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(756): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/Model/Resource/Paypal/Customer.php(45): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/Model/Paypal/Customer.php(53): IWD_Opc_Model_Resource_Paypal_Customer->getPaypalCustomerDataByField('customer_id', '9')
#8 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/Block/Customer/Account/Dashboard/Info.php(28): IWD_Opc_Model_Paypal_Customer->getPaypalCustomerDataByField('customer_id', '9')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/opc/customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml(8): IWD_Opc_Block_Customer_Account_Dashboard_Info->getPaypalCustomerEmail()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#11 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/Block/Customer/Account/Dashboard/Info.php(15): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): IWD_Opc_Block_Customer_Account_Dashboard_Info->_toHtml()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('paypalauth_dash...', true)
#17 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/Block/Customer/Account/Dashboard/Info.php(13): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('paypalauth_dash...')
#18 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): IWD_Opc_Block_Customer_Account_Dashboard_Info->_toHtml()
#19 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('info', true)
#21 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/dashboard.phtml(40): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('info')
#22 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#23 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#24 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(577): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('customer_accoun...', true)
#28 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Wrapper.php(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#29 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper->_toHtml()
#30 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#31 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#32 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#33 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#34 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/mobileshoppe/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(103): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#35 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#36 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#37 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#38 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#39 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#40 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#41 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(115): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#42 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->indexAction()
#43 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#44 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#45 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#46 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#47 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#48 {main}
```

Comment: The problem is that paypal module is not install properly so . Just check in db paypalauth_customer table created in db or not if yes then rename table name with mage1_9 prefix

Comment: The problem was with the one page checkout module as ProxiBlue eluded to.  It was overriding the original login functionality.  This was somewhat surprising given the popularity of that plugin along with the popularity of activating paypal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the 'missing' table, and if it is part of core magento. Most likely not. (don't have the time to dig into that)

But you can get your site logins working and then investigate further, without the pressure of a broken site on-top of that.

From your trace, you can see the issue is caused by a 3rd party module 'IWD_Opc', trying to display Paypal information in the customer panel.

This starts at #9 with the code `IWD_Opc_Block_Customer_Account_Dashboard_Info->getPaypalCustomerEmail()`

```
#6 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/Model/Resource/Paypal/Customer.php(45): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/Model/Paypal/Customer.php(53): IWD_Opc_Model_Resource_Paypal_Customer->getPaypalCustomerDataByField('customer_id', '9')
#8 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/Block/Customer/Account/Dashboard/Info.php(28): IWD_Opc_Model_Paypal_Customer->getPaypalCustomerDataByField('customer_id', '9')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/opc/customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml(8): IWD_Opc_Block_Customer_Account_Dashboard_Info->getPaypalCustomerEmail()
```

Thus, in some layout file (of that module) you will find that they include a block into the customer dashboard (info) section.

Have a look into that modules xml layout file, and look for an entry that references '`customer_account_dashboard_info`' something like `<reference name="customer_account_dashboard_info">`

and remove the entry, thus removing the custom block from the customer display.

Sorry, cannot be more specific, as I don't know that module's code, but this would give you an idea of what to do.

I would then make contact with that module's support team, and have them help you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that table for our module was not created during installation, so there are to ways:
1. you can try to create it in your database using this sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `paypalauth_customer` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `payer_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_UNIQUE_PAYER_ID` (`payer_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_ID` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `FK_CUSTOMER_PAYPAL_CUSTOMER_ID` (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


ALTER TABLE `paypalauth_customer`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_PAYPAL_CUSTOMER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

2. Open files:
   app/code/community/IWD/Opc/etc/config.xml
   and remove code:

```
            <opc_resource>
                <class>IWD_Opc_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <customer>
                        <table>paypalauth_customer</table>
                    </customer>
                </entities>
            </opc_resource>
```

open file
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/iwd_opc.xml
and remove sections:

```
<customer_account_index>
..
</customer_account_index>

<customer_account_login>
..
</customer_account_login>

<customer_account_create>
....
</customer_account_create>


and perhaps 
<opc_paypal_asklink>
...
</opc_paypal_asklink>
```

Comment: I fire query which is in step 1 , and it worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Forget all the complicated answers!
simple solution is to add the missing table "paypalauth_customer"

If you have a working installation of Magento go to it's database and save the paypalauth_customer table and import it into the one which throws the error.

Alternatively you can create an .sql file with the following code and import it into the database which has it missing

```
 -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.8.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Oct 26, 2015 at 07:52 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.42-37.1-log
-- PHP Version: 5.4.23

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `YOUR DATABASE`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `paypalauth_customer`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `paypalauth_customer`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `paypalauth_customer` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `payer_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_UNIQUE_PAYER_ID` (`payer_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_ID` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `FK_CUSTOMER_PAYPAL_CUSTOMER_ID` (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `paypalauth_customer`
--
ALTER TABLE `paypalauth_customer`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_PAYPAL_CUSTOMER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```